# How to prevent opening multiple copies of a .txt file?

Tags: windows, notepad

On my windows desktop, I have created shortcut to a file abc.txt. If I click on it twice, it opens two copies of the same file.

I want that by the second click, already opened file should come to active windows, instead of opening another copy. How can it be achieved?

Comment: This is a user function. Try Mouse Properties. Open Control Panel, Mouse, Buttons tab and set double click to Slow.  That should minimize your fast double click. Try that to see.

Comment: If you set a shortcut key and use the shortcut key a shortcut works how you want. But not by double clicking. Programs decide if they are single instance or not, not Windows.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is determined by each application when started by Windows.

Notepad is set to launch a new instance of itself each time, resulting in what you are seeing. Unfortunately Notepad doesn't provide a way to change this behaviour.

However, Notepad is only one text editor and there are many others you can download free and use instead, often for a much better editing experience. By selecting one that doesn't create a new instance of itself on each launch, you can easily get round this problem.

Many people find [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to be preferable to Notepad, and it is an example of a free editor that will give you the single-instance behaviour you are asking for.